# Hello, I'm so confused about this participial clause sentence

Tags: grammar

> Many college students living on their own for the first time incur far too much debt.

i was thoughtfully thinking about this sentence to figure out if this sentence is restrictive or not, but i couldn't.
i thought the phrase after Many college students, living on their own for the first time, limits the meaning of Many college students because thought that if i delete that phrase from the sentence, the subject Many college students will be generalized like "Mostly, Many college students have too much debt," which is so uncertain. However, my English book says it is a nonrestrictive participial clause so you can convert it to

> living on their own for the first time, many college students incur far too much debt.

so confused...any comments would be appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Many college students* [*living on their own for the first time*] *incur far too much* *debt*.

By virtue of being integrated into the syntactic structure, the bracketed clause is restrictive in that it serves semantically to identify which college students are being referred to, distinguishing students living on their own for the first time from other students.

The clause is a modifier in noun phrase structure, and has a similar meaning to the relative clause in *many students who are living on their own for the first time*, also restrictive.